# Function dialog cannot close my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to close the app when the user press the back button. My code works perfectly like that:

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async{    
    return (await showDialog(    
      context: context,    
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(    
        title: "Exit App?",    
        content: "Are you sure?",    
        actions: <Widget>[    
          new TextButton(    
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),    
            child: "NO",    
          ),    
          new TextButton(    
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),    
            child: "YES",    
          ),    
        ],    
      ),    
    ));    
}
```

If I define the same dialog inside a function:

```
void exitdialog(){    
    (the above dialog)
}
```

and then call the function to the point I want to exit, if I press yes only the dialog is closing, and if I add another    Navigator.of(context).pop(true)     then a black screen occurs. Any thoughts? I want to define the dialog inside a function in order for my code to be clear.In conclusion the thing that I am trying to do is:

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async{      
    exitdialog();    
}    

exitdialog(){
    return (showDialog(    
      context: context,    
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(    
        title: "Exit App?",    
        content: "Are you sure?",    
        actions: <Widget>[    
          new TextButton(    
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),    
            child: "NO",    
          ),    
          new TextButton(    
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),    
            child: "YES",    
          ),    
        ],    
      ),    
    ));  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function (may help's you):

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async{
  return (await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
      title: "Exit App?",
      content: "Are you sure?",
      actions: <Widget>[
        new TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: "NO",
        ),
        new TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Platform.isAndroid ? SystemNavigator.pop() : exit(0),
          child: "YES",
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

exit(0) not recommended to use, for iOS you can use [minimize_app](https://pub.dev/packages/minimize_app) plugin to minimize app instead of exit by this code:

```
MinimizeApp.minimizeApp();
```

Comment: This works! Is it safe though for iOS?

Comment: I read that SystemNavigator does not work for iOS and exit might cause problems!

Comment: exit(0) not recommended to use, for iOS you can use minimize_app plugin to minimize app instead of exit by this code: MinimizeApp.minimizeApp();

Comment: This option though does not kill the app and it leaves it running at the background

Comment: Apple does not recommend the force closing app, this is not UX friendly.

Comment: So in apple the only solution is to suspend the app?

Comment: exit dialog is not the common way in iOS. why you should implement force closing in iOS

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code hope its helpful to you. refer alert dialog [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)

use this package: `import 'dart:io';`

```
onWillPop() async {
      return (await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Exit App?"),
          content: Text("Are you sure?"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text('NO'),
            ),
            new TextButton(
              onPressed: () => exit(0),
              child: Text('YES'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
```

Your Widget:

```
Center(
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: onWillPop,
      child: Text('Press Me'),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: This code just close the dialog and does not exit my app

Comment: You want to exit your app when you pressed on YES button?

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do

Comment: @Michael Check my updated answer user `exit(0)` from `import 'dart:io';` package

Comment: This works for Android but for iOS it can cause many problems :(

Comment: Try `SystemNavigator.pop(),` instead of `exit(0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239576/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-michael).